# Android gms get travel duration without GoogleMap object

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to get travel duration between two points. How can I achieve this using Android GMS package? And can I do this without creation of GoogleMap object. You see, I need to calculate ETA between device position and other point purely by their coordinates.

I know I can do this in Google Maps API for Web (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) but I'm not allowed to launch MapView for this. Ideally duration should be calculated each time device position gets refreshed.

Comment: Don't you want to use this : [Google_Maps_Distance_Matrix_API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) ? It doesn't need any MapView as far as I'm seing.
There is even a [example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN)

Comment: This link is for web services api

Comment: Directions service doesn't require any mapview